# require: cannot load such file -- mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are few questions like this, but non of them seems is solving my problem.
I have a script that I want to run - `my_script.rb`
I am using `ruby-2.0.0-p353` and `rubygems 2.2.2`
I have installed it via `rvm`. When switch to use my custom-made gemset , `gem env` says:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-linux]
```

I use in my_script.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

require 'mysql2'
```

I have installed the gems via bundler and the gem list is saying:

```
Installing i18n (0.6.9) 
Installing multi_json (1.8.2) 
Installing activesupport (3.2.8) 
Installing builder (3.0.4) 
Installing activemodel (3.2.8) 
Installing activerecord (3.2.8) 
Installing treetop (1.4.15) 
Installing mime (0.2.0) 
Installing mysql2 (0.3.14) 
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Note: `my_script.rb` and `/vendor/bundle` are in the same directory

And now **the question**:

**Then why it is saying**:

```
kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
```

when I try to run my script with `./my_script`

**UPDATE:**

An update to myself :)
If this error occurs, try running a script with `bundle exec` as this was the primary intention of installing gems in bundle :)
I have been running the script the same way as I have used to on my server, but so I have forgot the most obvious and logical way - to run it with `bundle exec ./my_script.rb` as this was the primary goal for this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed them via bundlers, so you should let bundler require the gems. Add the following to the top of your script:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have forgot about that option. But I remember that I have run a script in different way, but yet, I might have installed the gems elsewhere some time ago. Thanks!